# Log messages containing a specific string to another file in rsyslogd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, logging, syslogd

I want to save my log messages generated by iptables to another file via rsyslogd.

Currently I use this code from `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-custom.conf`:

```
# Log cron to cron.log and not to syslog
*.*;cron,auth,authpriv.none         -/var/log/syslog
cron.*                               /var/log/cron.log

# Log firewall to extra log
:msg,contains,"[BLOCK " /var/log/firewall.log

& stop
```

My cron logs are fine, they get logged only to `cron.log`, but my iptables logs get logged in both `syslog` and `firewall.log`. Is there a way to only log it in `firewall.log`?

My system specs:

```
> rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd 8.16.0, compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
        PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        memory allocator:                       system default
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes
        Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

`Linux MYHOSTNAME 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the firewall logging part before other rules, so that it looks like

```
# Log firewall to extra log
:msg,contains,"[BLOCK " /var/log/firewall.log
& stop

# Log cron to cron.log and not to syslog
*.*;cron,auth,authpriv.none         -/var/log/syslog
cron.*                               /var/log/cron.log
```

The rules are considered in order, so as you have it now a message matching **.*;cron,auth,authpriv.none* will always be written to syslog, even if it also matches *:msg,contains,"[BLOCK "* and is written to firewall.log.
The stop command is simply too late in the file to stop anything.

See also https://www.rsyslog.com/writing-specific-messages-to-a-file-and-discarding-them/

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, works fine now!